# Android: How to show toolbar when the list is scrolled to top?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I have a problem with toolbar, when I scroll up, the toolbar hide, and when I scroll down, the toolbar show immediately. I want to scroll to top of RecyclerView, the toolbar will show, how can I do it?

Thanks!!!!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:id="@id/dn_main_container"
                                             android:background="@android:color/white"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:context=".phone.activity.ActivityPerspective">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="-56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleView"
                    android:text="Author"
                    android:textSize="9pt"
                    android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:src="@drawable/search_dark"
                android:paddingTop="19dp"
                android:paddingBottom="19dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in child(in your case `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`) of `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>` to achieve on scroll down hide app bar and on scroll top show app bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use below format code this will work for you what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_notice"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</FrameLayout>
```

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_help);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```